# zcat a file, output its contents to another file based on original filename

Tags: backup, gzip, zcat

I'm looking to create a bash/perl script in Linux that will restore .gz files based on filename:

```
_path_to_file.txt.gz
_path_to_another_file.conf.gz
```

Where the underscores form the directory structure.. so the two above would be:

```
/path/to/file.txt
/path/to/another/file.conf
```

These are all in the /backup/ directory..

I want to write a script that will cat each .gz file into its correct location by changing the _ to / to find the correct path - so that the contents of _path_to_another_file.conf.gz replaces the text in /path/to/another/file.conf

```
zcat _path_to_another_file.conf.gz > /path/to/another/file.conf
```

I've started by creating a file with the correct destination filenames in it.. I could create another file to list the original filenames in it and have the script go through line by line?

```
ls /backup/ |grep .gz > /backup/backup_files && sed -i 's,_,\/,g' /backup/backup_files && cat /backup/backup_files
```

Whatcha think?

Comment: Aloha, Rob! StackOverflow is a great site. If you read the "About" page found at the top of this page by the search-bar, you get a badge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a Bash script that should do what you want :

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.gz; do
    n=$(echo $f | tr _ /)
    zcat $f > ${n%.*}
done
```

It loops over all files that end with .gz, and extracts them into the path represented by their filename with `_` replaced with `/`.

Comment: Thanks!  Tried the first version and had the .gz.. so i was going to cut it off..  then saw you updated it..  this current one writes a file called ${n%.*} into the backup directory though..

Comment: Sorry for that, I didn't test it on my side... this one should work though, removed the quotes around the `${n%.*}`.

Answer (score 2):

That's not necessarily an invertible mapping (what if the original file is named `high_scores` for instance? is that encoded specially, e.g., with double underscore as `high__scores.gz`?) but if you just want to take a name and translate `_` to `/` and remove `.gz` at the end, `sed` will do it:

```
for name in /backup/*.gz; do
    newname=$(echo "$name" |
        sed -e 's,^/backup/,,' \
            -e 's,_,/,g' \
            -e 's/\.gz$//')
    echo "zcat $name > $newname"
done
```

Make sure it works right (the above is completely untested!) then take out the echo, leaving:

```
    zcat "$name" > "$newname"
```

(the quotes protect against white space in the names).